# Does "scoping into" a class's header file in C++ create an instance of it?

Tags: c++, memory

As part of a project I am working on I have to design a discrete vector calculus calculator. Additionally, the main program has to be able to handle pretty large data sets. My idea was to make a class called `Calculator` which only has functions as members. So I thought of two ways to use the functions inside `Calculator` as shown below:

The first way is to just instantiate the class and use its members like so:

```
/* inside main program */
Vector V;
Calculator calc;
Vector Vgrad = calc.gradient( V );
```

The other way (I think) is to just "scope in" and hopefully this doesn't instantiate the class:

```
/* inside main program */
Vector V;
Vector Vgrad = Calculator::gradient( V );
```

I am wondering if the second version skips having to instantiate the class. This code is being run in parallel and I don't want each thread to create its own `Calculator` in order to save space. So I am wondering if the second way of writing it is (a) valid, and (b) more memory economic. Any other design ideas are welcome, but keep in mind that I want to keep these entities in a class for readability.

Comment: all you save is one byte, since you don't have anything in the class, and it must get some minimal allocation.

Comment: @SHR that's not bad then because there will be multiple threads using this (up to thousands) so it should help a lot!

Comment: Thousands of threads? That's the design problem you should be focusing on.

Comment: @PeteBecker haha well frankly this was not my choice and that is just a guess, I don't really know how many they're doing. I was only assigned the calculator and a few other modules. This is part of a large project involving a couple dozen designers and will eventually run on a Cray. But I do know that `Calculator` has to be used trillions of times in one execution of the main.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the second approach does not instantiate any class. It's not that the overhead is massive, but this does save a few bits, here and there.

As an alternative just consider declaring a `Calculator` namespace; if all you want is a different scope. A class with no non-static members and methods, and with only static methods or members, is, pretty much, just a namespace of its own.

Comment: If I make it a namespace can it still be a template? I didn't mention it here but this `Calculator` module will be used by other teams for different purposes. Would the namespace have that versatility? Thanks!

Comment: @MBarbosa A function can be templated regardless of whether it's in a namespace or a class.

Comment: @JamesAdkison thanks! I will have to look into how to make a namespace, but doesn't seem like much of a stretch from a class. I've used them before of course, just never have had to make one.